# Solving the limit $\lim_n \left(1+\frac{1}{-n} \right)^{-n}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I was doing an exercise about limits of sequences and arrived at the following limit:
$$\lim_n \left(1+\frac{1}{-n} \right)^{-n}\ \ \ \ (1)$$

We are supposed to solve the limit without using L'hopital's rule. The only limit that's similar to this one that I know is:

$$\lim_n \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e\ \ \ \ (2)$$

But I have no clue how to get to something similar to $(2)$ starting from (1). How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're taking $n\to\infty$ in these limits. We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac n{n-1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^n$$ by algebra. Clearly this equals
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n+1}$$
after replacing $n$ by $n+1$. I leave it to you to proceed from here by splitting this into two pieces.

Comment: Finishing what @Funktorality has started:<br>$$\lim_{n\to\infty}({1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}({1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}({1+\frac{1}{n}})^{}$$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}({1+\frac{1}{n}})^{n}=e$$$$\lim_{n\to\infty}({1+\frac{1}{n}})^{}=1$$$$\text{So the answer is just } e $$<br>(aside from that, my solution was going to be identical, so I hope you don't mind it as a comment)